# конфликт баз данных postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

Хочу создать подключение в PostgresSQL через docker-compose

мой docker-compose:

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin

    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge


volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

мой application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  application:
    name: customer
  datasource:
    username: 'postgres'
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/customer
    password: 'root'
  jpa:
      properties:
        hibernate:
          dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
          format_sql: 'true'
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: update
      show-sql: 'true'
```

Создаю базу данных на самом pgadmin: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создаю сервер: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у меня на компьютере так же установлен postgres и видимо возникает конфликт и он не может найти базу данных на docker'е

Возникающая ошибка:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ВАЖНО: база данных "customer" не
> существует (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be windows-1251,
> if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or
> host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)  at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2565)
> ~[postgresql-42.2.24.jar:42.2.24]     at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2677)
> ~[postgresql-42.2.24.jar:42.2.24]     at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.(QueryExecutorImpl.java:147)
> ~[postgresql-42.2.24.jar:42.2.24]     at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:273)
> ~[postgresql-42.2.24.jar:42.2.24]     at
> org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
> ~[postgresql-42.2.24.jar:42.2.24]     at
> org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:225)
> ~[postgresql-42.2.24.jar:42.2.24]     at
> org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
> ~[postgresql-42.2.24.jar:42.2.24]     at
> org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
> ~[postgresql-42.2.24.jar:42.2.24]     at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
> ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]  at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
> ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]  at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
> ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]  at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
> ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]  at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
> ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]  at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115)
> ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]  at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
> ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]  at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
> ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
> ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
> ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
> ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
> ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]   at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:765)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:445)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
> ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]    at
> org.example.CustomerApplication.main(CustomerApplication.java:9)
> ~[classes/:na]

Прошу помочь в решении проблемы взаимодействия постгресов.

Comment: Вы уверены, что у вас два postgres работают? Один из них должен был отвалится при запуске из-за того, что порт 5432 уже занят.

Comment: да работаю два postgres. вот на скриншоте видно https://yapx.ru/album/V90Zd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPD:
Поменяйте в docker-compose порт, например на:

```
ports:
    - "5434:5432"
```

И поменяйте в application.yml:

```
url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5434/customer
```

Для подключения в pgAdmin к базе, в вкладке Connection согласно docker-compose:

```
Host name/address: postgres
Port:              5432
```

Comment: а при создании сервера тоже указать порт 5433 ?

Comment: Нет, остальное оставьте как есть. Пересобирите образ докера после того как поменяете  docker-compose, и запустите докер. После запуска вы можете посмотреть на каком порту запустилась контейнер. Потом меняете application.yml и перезапускаете сервер.

Comment: все запустилось на порту 5434 и создалась база данных. но теперь другая проблема. он не видит сервер. вот на скрине так: https://yapx.ru/album/V90z2

Comment: Попробуйте поменять порт на 5434 в вкладке Connection в поле port. Как на 3-м скрине в вашем запросе.
Если это не поможет напишите пожалуйста мне в телеграм: @MuhaPW